# Pythonic way of converting dict of lists to list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following datastructure:

```
[('dim1', ['All', 'All', 'All']),
 ('dim2', ['100', '100', '100']),
 ('min', [1500, 1200, 1300]),
 ('max', [2500, 2200, 2000]),
 ('kpi', ['Avg prod', 'Avg prod', 'Sales'])]
```

and I want the following:

```
[{'dim1': 'All', 'dim2': '100', 'min': 1500, 'max': 2500, 'kpi': 'Avg prod'},
{'dim1': 'All', 'dim2': '100', 'min': 1200, 'max': 2200, 'kpi': 'Avg prod'},
{'dim1': 'All', 'dim2': '100', 'min': 1300, 'max': 2000, 'kpi': 'Avg Sales'}]
```

I want to achive this nicely and pythonic and avoiding nested loops as much as possible. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Yes of course that makes sense, and I thought about including my attempt so far. But considering this is such a short and easy problem I figured someone will know this by heart and will be able to answer quickly.

Comment: Your input data is a list of tuples, not a "dict of lists" as described in your question's title.  (It could become one, though, by being wrapped in a call to `dict()`.  Was that your intent?)  Which is correct: the sample input or the title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lst = [
...     ('dim1', ['All', 'All', 'All']),
...     ('dim2', ['100', '100', '100']),
...     ('min', [1500, 1200, 1300]),
...     ('max', [2500, 2200, 2000]),
...     ('kpi', ['Avg prod', 'Avg prod', 'Sales'])
... ]
>>>
>>> keys, values = zip(*lst)
>>> [dict(zip(keys, vs)) for vs in zip(*values)]
[{'dim1': 'All', 'max': 2500, 'dim2': '100', 'kpi': 'Avg prod', 'min': 1500},
 {'dim1': 'All', 'max': 2200, 'dim2': '100', 'kpi': 'Avg prod', 'min': 1200},
 {'dim1': 'All', 'max': 2000, 'dim2': '100', 'kpi': 'Sales', 'min': 1300}]
```

Comment: Cool, never thougth about the use of zip(*list) before. It's basically transposition which was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Oneliner:

```
data = [('dim1', ['All', 'All', 'All']),
        ('dim2', ['100', '100', '100']),
        ('min', [1500, 1200, 1300]),
        ('max', [2500, 2200, 2000]),
        ('kpi', ['Avg prod', 'Avg prod', 'Sales'])]

result = (lambda h, l: [dict(zip(h, i)) for i in zip(*l)])(*zip(*data))
```

*this is effectively the same as falsetru's answer that I arrived to independently, excepting that the application is with a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Python beginner:

1. As every second item from the list elements have `length 3`. Use `for loop` to iterate 3 times by using `range()` method.
2. As every element type of output list is dictionary., so define  dictionary i.e. `tmp={}`.
3. As we want to add every input list element to tmp dictionary.
4. Append tmp to output list.
5. print final output list.

code:

```
input = [('dim1', ['All', 'All', 'All']),
 ('dim2', ['100', '100', '100']),
 ('min', [1500, 1200, 1300]),
 ('max', [2500, 2200, 2000]),
 ('kpi', ['Avg prod', 'Avg prod', 'Sales'])]

output = []

for i in range(0,3):
    tmp = {}
    for j in input:
        tmp[j[0]] = j[1][i]
    output.append(tmp)

import pprint
pprint.pprint(output)
```

output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 11.py 
[{'dim1': 'All', 'dim2': '100', 'kpi': 'Avg prod', 'max': 2500, 'min': 1500},
 {'dim1': 'All', 'dim2': '100', 'kpi': 'Avg prod', 'max': 2200, 'min': 1200},
 {'dim1': 'All', 'dim2': '100', 'kpi': 'Sales', 'max': 2000, 'min': 1300}]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Thats a great working solution and similar to something I had drafted up myself. What I didn't like about it was the nested loops, somewhat confusing indexes and temporary variables. Take a look at Falsetru's solution and try to work out how it works for some really nice pythonic code!